# Different Methods for Twig Templating (October CMS) to Create Messages for the Translate Plugin

Tags: twig, octobercms

I'm just curious as to how it would be possible to set up different ways of creating messages for the October CMS translate plugin.

I already know how to use the standard method for creating a message like so...

```
{{ "This is text to be translated."|_ }}
```

But, how would you translate something like...

```
{{ variable }}
```

Or...

```
{{ post.variable|raw }}
```

And, lastly...

```
{{ post.variable }}
```

Comment: Just the same as your first example, the `raw` one should become `{{ var | _ | raw }}` though

Comment: That method did not work though. By the way, I'm using post.content_html|_|raw, or the variable I'm using is content_html. However, this variable is not highlighted.